# Why is a switch statement used before call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, laravel, switch-statement, magic-methods

I've been looking through the laravel source code and I stumbled across this in the callStatic magic method:

```
switch (count($args)) {
    case 0:
        return $instance->$method();
    case 1:
        return $instance->$method($args[0]);
    case 2:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);
    case 3:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
    case 4:
        return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
    default:
        return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $args);
}
```

Why is the switch statement used first and then call_user_func_array()?

Comment: Probably for performance. `call_user_func_array` is slower than invoking the method directly, so for the majority of cases (up to 4 args) the direct method is used

Comment: May be code is not going through any case, so default is executing first

Comment: check value of count($args)

Comment: I would also say it's simply a performance optimization because calling a function directly is faster then calling it with call_user_func_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Clive has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462124/why-is-a-switch-statement-used-before-call-user-func-array#comment70129788_41462124) in the comments; it's because of the performance concerns.

[`call_user_func_array()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4848) is widely known for its performance issues. It's even slower than its sister function `call_user_func()` by **10-20%** as some benchmarks revealed.

Here's the result of a benchmark ran to compare the performance of straight calls vs. dynamic calls vs. calls through `call_user_func*` functions:

> - Dynamic function calls are slightly slower than straight calls (the former have an extra interpretive layer to determine the function to call
>     `call_user_func()` is about 50% slower, and `call_user_func_array()` is about 100% slower than a straight function call.
> - Static and regular method calls are roughly equivalent to function calls
>     `call_user_func()` on method calls is typically slower than `call_user_func_array()`, and the faster operation usually takes at least twice the execution time of a straight call.
>     *— [Matthew Weier O'Phinney](https://mwop.net/blog/121-Benchmarking-dynamic-functionmethod-calls.html)*

Paul M. Jones, another well-known PHP developer, also ran a benchmark on the exact same subject and concluded that:

> So native calls to `htmlentities()` are twice as fast as doing effectively the same thing via `call_user_func()` with an object method, and using `call_user_func_array()` is **10-20%** slower than using `call_user_func()`...
>
> Clearly, PHP has to do a lot more work behind the scenes to map the variables to objects and parameters when using `call_user_func_array()`.
>   *— [Paul M. Jones](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/182)*

#### Argument Unpacking

One last thing; As of PHP 5.6 and with the [advent](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/477/files#diff-3a8139128d4026ce0cb0c86beba4e6b9R2700) of argument unpacking operator (AKA *spread*, *splat* or *scatter* operator), you can safely rewrite that code to:

```
$instance->$method(...$args);
```

Quoting from the [Argument Unpacking PHP RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking):

> Furthermore `call_user_func_array` has a rather large performance impact. If a large number of calls go through it, this can make a significant difference. **For this reason, projects like Laravel and Drupal often replace particularly common** `call_user_func_array` **calls with a switch statements**.
>
> The `...` argument unpacking syntax is about **3.5 to 4 times faster than** `call_user_func_args`. This solves the performance issue. Benchmark code and results.

Also, see:
[Argument unpacking advantages over `call_user_func_array`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking#advantages_over_call_user_func_array)